# How to create a border + border colour field on an image

Tags: assets, field, image

My first question here... maybe one of a few! I've inherited a Craft project recently and don't have much experience with it.

I want to allow admin to set a border (and border color) whenever they add an image. Currently, the `image` field has a field type of `Assets`. I don't want to change the field type (to a `Super Table` or similar) because the component is used in so many other places - it would break.

We're using Craft 2 but upgrading to 3 presently.

Has anyone else had to do this before? Any suggestions on how to approach this? Let me know if I can clarify anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a Matrix block with a field inside a block called Image. Given that information, I'd add a new field to that block called Border. You could either use a colour field, or a dropdown to set your own values. Then maybe something like this on the front end:

```
{% if block.image|length %}
<img src="{{ block.image.one.url }}" {% if block.border|length %} class="bordered border-{{ block.border }}"{% endif %}>
{% endif %}
```

Craft doesn't have any relation to the front end of your site intrinsically, so you could call the field whatever you like.

Comment: Ahh, yes - I'd totally missed that I could do that. Thanks Daryl.